# how to call jquery function by its name

Tags: jquery, call

How to call jQuery function by its name. For example:

```
var fn = 'hide',
    myObj = $("#smth");

// here I want to hide myObj ( $("#smth").hide() )

// my variants were:
// fn.call(myObj) - doesn't work
// myObj.fn() - doesn't work (I've not expected, just tried =) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the function as you would access any other member of `myObj` using a variable name, and then simply call it:

```
var fn = 'hide',
myObj = $("#smth");
(myObj[fn])();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var fn = 'hide',
myObj = $("#smth");

myObj[fn]();
```

Cheers